# Reverse individual words in a string

Tags: vba

I got quite a challenging assignment to " introduce " us (as a mathematics class) to VBA. Don't ask me why.

I've asked this question a few hours ago, but I hadn't quite described the (weird) restrictions that are part of the assignment.

They want us to write code that reverses the sentence "VBA is amazing" word by word. So the outcome must be: "ABV si gnizama". And now comes the challenging part; **The only functions that are allowed are *Len* and *Mid***

The sentence "VBA is amazing" may be followed by a space to make it easier..

I was thinking of a while-loop where I can find the first word in the sentence:

```
Do While Mid(Sentence, i, 1) <> " "
 i = i+1
Loop
```

That should give the position of the first space and thereby the length (i-1) of the first word.

And then I would maybe use a nested for-loop to assign Mid(Sentence, x, 1) = Mid(Sentence,z,1) with x from 1 to i-1 and z from i-1 to 1, but I'm too new to VBA to know how.

I've got code that puts out: "gnizama si ABV", but that's not what this is about.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66261967/edit) the code that did a complete reversal into the question?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: This is not a challenging task by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: It's the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259719/how-do-i-reverse-individual-words-in-a-string-in-vba

Comment: In looking at your other question, there appears to be an answer that only uses Mid and Len.  Does this not fulfill your requirements?

Comment: @BrianMStafford Could you point out which one? I've checked them all.

Comment: @JordivanSelm Perhaps the answer by Maciej Los?  It uses Len and Mid, but I guess it  uses InStr, too, so that may disqualify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use only `Len` and `Mid` then this will do it.

```
Sub ReverseStringByWord()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim newstr As String
    Dim wordbreak As Long
    Dim mystr As String
    mystr = "VBA is amazing"
    
    wordbreak = 1

    For i = 1 To Len(mystr)
        If Mid(mystr, i, 1) = " " Then
            wordbreak = i
            newstr = newstr & Mid(mystr, i, 1)
        Else
            If wordbreak > 1 Then
                newstr = Mid(newstr, 1, wordbreak) & Mid(mystr, i, 1) & Mid(newstr, wordbreak + 1, Len(newstr))
            Else
                newstr = Mid(mystr, i, 1) & newstr
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print mystr, newstr
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks quite understandable. I will answer my own question when I get " the answer " from my teacher.